# VirtualWebappLoader - is it a good option to use in production?

Tags: tomcat7

Currently our Ops team has to repackage the war file that we release with instance specific configuration. They are requesting us to externalize the configuration files (log4j.properties, environment.properties, jrf.properties, quartz.properties) out size the war file. That will make the deployment easier.

We are using Tomcat 7 and VirtualWebappLoader in Tomcat 7 looks like a very cool feature to externalize the configuration outside the war file.

Tomcat 6 documentation explicitly states that "This is not meant to be used for production. Its meant to ease development with IDE's without the need for fully republishing jars in WEB-INF/lib"?

Tomcat 7 documentation does not say so.

Any idea if VirtualWebappLoader feature can be used in production environment?

Thanks,
Ashish

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Virtual_webapp

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/VirtualWebappLoader.html

Comment: +1 I would be interested to hear opinions on this as well. Are you referencing the external dependencies from a central location?

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is old but since I just was investigating about the use of the VirtualWebAppLoader for a production server and saw other Stackoverflow related talking about this, I'd like to add this answer.

As reported [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55478), this warning is no more in place at least as of Tomcat 6.0.38+ (and Tomcat 7 too).

Excerpt:
"Since this limitation is not given anymore and has been removed from Tomcat 7 JavaDocs, one should remove this erroneous warning from version 6 too."